# Testcafe verification ignores specified 'timeout'

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe

My question is pretty simple - why testcafe verifications ignore timeout, which I set in options?

For example next method, called for a page that will never be loaded, didnt wait 20 minutes until fail, it fails faster, ignoring timeout

```
waitForPageLoad: async (expectedUrl: string) => {
    var getPageState: ClientFunction = ClientFunction(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
         resolve(document.readyState as string);
      });
    }).with({ boundTestRun: testController });

    await testController.expect(((await getPageState()) as string) === "complete").ok({ timeout: 1200000});
  }
}
```

(method call and all methods above have 'await' keyword)

Is there any explanations for such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your assertions. See the following example based on the changeable `document.a` property:

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.a = '0';

    window.setTimeout(() => { document.a = '1' }, 10000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page('./index.html');

test('test', async t => {
    const getPageState = ClientFunction(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(document.a);
        });
    });

    await t.expect(getPageState()).eql('1', { timeout: 1000 }); // it fails, increase the timeout (15000) to pass
});
```